# Why is my .fetchone function returning "none"?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Username is a variable that is drawn from an Entrybox using tkinter. I need for dbsalt to return the outcome of the cursor1.execute query as a string, but it returns "none" or presents a traceback that states "NoneType has no attribute **getitem**". I do not understand what is incorrect.

```
def login_verification(self):

    sql = ("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = %s")
    username = self.KUEntry.get()
    print username
    cursor1.execute(sql, username)
    dbsalt = cursor1.fetchone() [0]
    print dbsalt

    sql2 = ("SELECT PashHash FROM User WHERE username = %s")
    cursor2.execute(sql2, username)
    dbhash = cursor2.fetchone() [0]
    print dbhash

    test = hashlib.sha512(username + dbsalt).hexdigest()
    print test

    if test == dbhash:
        self.intro_screen
    else:
        print "incorrect password"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call `execute` method, but assigned to it. Call it using `cursor.execute(..)`:

And you should use `'` to quote the string.

```
username = self.KUEntry.get()

cursor1.execute("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = '%s'" % username)
dbsalt = str(cursor1.fetchone())
print dbsalt
```

BTW, it is better to use parameter passing style than manually formatting string to prevent SQL injection.

```
cursor1.execute("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = %s", [username])
```

Comment: unfortunately, calling returned an error. here is my code (sorry for the format)         `username = self.KUEntry.get()

        sql = ("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = %s", [username])
        cursor1.execute(sql)
        dbsalt = str(cursor1.fetchone())
        print dbsalt`

Comment: Here is the traceback: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./Uninote.py", line 104, in login_verification
    cursor1.execute(sql)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 529, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @codeLearnerCamel, What do you get if you print the `username`? Show me the output `print(repr(username))`

Comment: @codeLearnerCamel, It seems like `username` is not a string, but a tuple; replace `username` with `username[0]` (you may need to use other index depending on the structure of the tuple) in (`cursor1.execute("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = %s", [username])`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but unfortunately, that did not work either. When i do a print statement for the username, it returns what is typed into the entrybox. That i know for sure works.

Comment: @codeLearnerCamel, Instead of explainig what's printed, please show me the output as is. (Copy & paste)

Comment: Copy and Pasted here is what I get:                                                        Username
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./*******.py", line 122, in login_verification
    cursor1.execute(sql, username)
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: @codeLearnerCamel, I meant the output of `print(repr(username))`.

Comment: @codeLearnerCamel, BTW, the statement should be `cursor1.execute(sql, [username])`, not `cursor1.execute(sql, username)`  / or `cursor1.execute(sql, [username[0]])` (depending on what the `username` contains; that's why I asked you show me the output of `print(repr(username))`

Comment: added the brackets around username worked for me actually. Thank you so much @falsetru I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: I didn't intend to be difficult, I hadn't fully understood what you were asking until now